# Transforming an XML file into RDF with blank nodes

Tags: xml, xslt, rdf, blank-nodes

I am quite new in using XSLT.

I am writing an XSL transformation from an XML (metadata) document into an XML/RDF, and I am also improving the model underlying the original document. In specific, the original document describes a Person, and at some point it lists all of the person's names:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Person RecordID="abcd">
    <PersonNames>
        <PersonName>
            <Surname>Doe</Surname>
            <FirstName>John</FirstName>
        </PersonName>
        <PersonName>
            <Surname>Doe</Surname>
            <FirstName>Janine</FirstName>
        </PersonName>
        <PersonName>
            <Surname>Smith</Surname>
            <FirstName>Janine</FirstName>
        </PersonName>
    </PersonNames>
</Person>
```

I don't want to connect the person's URI to each of these items separately, as by doing so it is unclear that 'Joe Smith' has never been a name of this person. I'd rather use a blank node for each name, and then link FirstName and Surname to the corresponding blank node; however, I cannot find a solution to generate a blank node's ID (which I would do inside the xsl:for-each loop that goes through all the person's names) that I can then call outside the loop and refer to.

Intuitively, I would create an id personNameID for each of these  element, and then, outside the loop (and outside the  subtree), I would add the corresponding triples. The outcome would be something like:

```
<rdf:RDF 'namespaces'>
    <localontology:Person>
    ... person's metadata ...
    <foaf:name rdf:nodeID="name1">
    <foaf:name rdf:nodeID="name2">
    ....
</localontology:Person>
<rdf:Description rdf:nodeID="name1">
    <localontology:firstName 'FirstName in name1'>
    <localontology:surname 'Surname in name1'>
</rdf:Description>
<rdf:Description rdf:nodeID="name1">
    <localontology:firstName 'FirstName in name2'>
    <localontology:surname 'Surname in name2'>
</rdf:Description>
```

I really don't know which functions/constructs I could use... is there someone who can help?

Comment: Your question is not clear: what is the requested output of your example (assuming that what you posted is the input)?

Comment: sorry, I pressed the button "post" before being done with editing! Is it clear enough this way?

Comment: Sorry, no. I don't know what you mean by "triples" or "blank node".

Comment: a triple is a statement in RDF (subject predicate object). A blank node is a node that does not have a URI that makes sense outside the RDF graph where that node is used. One of the tags of this question is RDF, and while I'm quite expert in that, I'm quite ignorant in XSLT.

Comment: I believe this question is purely and squarely about XSLT, and you should present it as such (i.e. post minimal, but complete examples of the input and the **matching** required output and explain the logic of the required transformation).  You should not presume or require RDF expertise on the part of those who would answer, unless you are willing to wait until someone who is expert in both will appear.

Comment: thanks for the hint, I'll try to reformulate

Comment: actually I think having RDF knowledge helps understanding the question.

Answer (score 0):

I would not use blank nodes here. The blank nodes can have an uri such as localontology:JohnDoe which then has a firstName and surname as property. Such a uri is meaningfull and when people share a name you can reuse the same instance. If you need help generating such an uri leave a comment.

If you insist on using blank nodes you can use number() and/or position() to get the current node and use this to generate a uri. http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_number.asp